# Grouping string input by count

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a question out of my book and it asks:

> Implement function names that takes no input and repeatedly asks the
>   user to enter a student's first name. When the user enters a blank
>   string, the function should print for every name, the number of
>   students with that name.

Example usage:

```
Usage:
names()
Enter next name: Valerie
Enter next name: Bob
Enter next name: Valerie
Enter next name: John
Enter next name: Amelia
Enter next name: Bob
Enter next name: 
There is 1 student named Amelia
There are 2 students named Bob
There is 1 student named John
There are 2 students named Valerie
```

So far I have this code:

```
def names():
    names = []
    namecount = {a:name.count(a) for a in names}
    while input != (''):
        name = input('Enter next name: ')
        names = name
        if input == ('')
            for x in names.split():
                print ('There is', x ,'named', names[x])
```

I'm really lost here and any input would help out tons. Also if possible please explain how to fix my code

Comment: @NPE I think he means to explain our answers

Comment: @Haidro Yes that's what I meant, sorry for the confusion. I'm just really lost here and I've been struggling on this question for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with namings in your function, you are using such variables like 'names' that is used for function name as well as 'input' that is a python function name for reading user input - so you have to avoid using this. Also you defining a namecount variable as a dict and trying to initialize it before fill. So try to check solution below:

```
def myFunc():
    names = []
    name = ''
    while True: #bad stuff you can think on your own condition
        name = raw_input('press space(or Q) to exit or enter next name: ')
        if name.strip() in ('', 'q', 'Q'):
            for x in set(names):
                print '{0} is mentioned {1} times'.format(x, names.count(x))
            break
        else:
            names.append(name)

myFunc()
```

OR:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def myFunc():
    names = defaultdict(int)
    name = ''
    while True: #bad stuff you can think on your own condition
        name = raw_input('press space(or Q) to exit or enter next name: ')
        if name.strip() in ('', 'q', 'Q'):
            for x in set(names):
                print '{0} is mentioned {1} times'.format(x, names[x])
            break
        else:
            names[name] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your function for you:

```
def names():
    names = {} # Creates an empty dictionary called names
    name = 'cabbage' # Creates a variable, name, so when we do our while loop, 
                     # it won't immediately break
                     # It can be anything really. I just like to use cabbage
    while name != '': # While name is not an empty string
        name = input('Enter a name! ') # We get an input
        if name in names: # Checks to see if the name is already in the dictionary
            names[name] += 1 # Adds one to the value
        else: # Otherwise
            names[name] = 1 # We add a new key/value to the dictionary
    del names[''] # Deleted the key '' from the dictionary
    for i in names: # For every key in the dictionary
        if names[i] > 1: # Checks to see if the value is greater for 1. Just for the grammar :D
            print("There are", names[i], "students named", i) # Prints your expected output
        else: # This runs if the value is 1
            print("There is", names[i], "student named", i) # Prints your expected output
```

When doing `names()`:

```
Enter a name! bob
Enter a name! bill
Enter a name! ben
Enter a name! bob
Enter a name! bill
Enter a name! bob
Enter a name! 
There are 3 students named bob
There are 2 students named bill
There is 1 student named ben
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback! Your comments really helped me in seeing how the code works

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse your code:

```
def names():
    names = []
    namecount = {a:name.count(a) for a in names}
    while input != (''):
        name = input('Enter next name: ')
        names = name
        if input == ('')
            for x in names.split():
                print ('There is', x ,'named', names[x])
```

There seem to be a few problems, let's list them

1. The `while` loop's conditional

   - What you want to do check if input from user is `''` (nothing)..
   - `input` is a built-in function for getting input from user, so it never will be `('')`.
2. The `names = name` statement

   - What you want to do is add `name` to the list `names`.
   - Here you are changing `names` to a string, which isn't what you want.
3. The `if`'s conditional

   - same as 1.
4. The `for` loop

   - let's ignore.. just not valid.. here..

We fix these problems as follows(solution has same numbering as problem above that it solves)

1. Change the conditional to something like `name != ''`. 
   Also, before the loop begins, you need to get input once for this to work, which in this case has a bonus, the first input can have a different prompt.
2. Use `names.append(name)` to add `name` to `names`.
3. Same as 1.
4. Just look at the for loop below...

Try this

```
def names():
    names = []
    name = input('Enter a name: ').strip() # get first name
    while name != '':
        names.append(name)
        name = raw_input('Enter next name: ').strip() # get next name

    for n in set(names): # in a set, no values are repeated
        print '%s is mentioned %s times' % (n, names.count(n)) # print output
```

Comment: Hello. You translated from french to english my answer to this question : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336747/python-and-string-extraction#comment21659597_15336747) Not a big problem. But you completly changed the content, hence the sense. I didn't evoke SQL and you did, adding _"It can be complicated to process a variety of bases and and text."_ , implying that my answer using regular expression wasn't adapted. That's your opinion, not mine. I didn't appreciate. So I deleted "my" answer.

Comment: @eyquem  that's what [google](http://translate.google.co.in/#auto/en/Bonjour%0A%0Afait%20ce%20qu%27il%20faut.%20Ce%20peut%20%C3%AAtre%20complexifi%C3%A9%20pour%20pouvoir%20traiter%20une%20vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20de%20bases%20et%20et%20de%20texte) said... So, consider it Google's opinion :). Sorry... I just added the part which said about the MySQL libraries...

Comment: Google's translation is _"do the right thing. It can be complicated to process a variety of databases and text and"_ (by the way, it should be **does the right thing**, Google's translation is bad) but the content in the modified answer is _"Use what it needs (a proper sql library). It can be complicated to process a variety of bases and and text."_ Will you pretend that it's the same ? I didn't write the phrase **a proper sql library**, I didn't write **Use what it needs**.

Comment: Moreover, the Google's translation you present as what you copied to modify my answer ends with _".... a variety of databases and text and"_ wheras in the modified answer there is _"...a variety of bases and and text."_ There are two 'and' in each phrase, but they aren't placed at the same position: very strange to pretend that you copied the second phrase, and I read the first. It smells as if you are trying to delude me.

Comment: Oh I've just seen that you are 14. I will forgive you. Buit that's very astonishing that guy aged 14 dares to modify the answer of someone else !

Comment: @eyquem  1. I'm not trying to delude you 2. I was just trying to make sense of what you had written. Sorry Again. Also, it seems that the only comments in my answer's comments are yours and mine, which are on a different topic. So, consider deleting those comment. Sorry again. I don't think that is a very daring thing to do ( as there are other people who review my edit )..

Answer (score 0):

```
def names():
      counters = {}

      while True:
            name = input('Enter next name:')

            if name == ' ':
                  break

            if name in counters:
                  counters[name] += 1
            else:
                  counters[name] = 1
      for name in counters:
            if counters[name] == 1:
                  print('There is {} student named {}'.format(counters[name],name))
            else:
                  print('There are {} student named {}'.format(counters[name],name))


names()
```