# python and string extraction

Tags: python, string

I have tons of lines like this:

```
13480 AAA BBB CCC
```

I'd like to convert them using python in something like:

```
SELECT XX FROM YY WHERE SOUNDEX("AAA BBB CCC")=FIELD1 AND CP="13480"
```

Knowing that "`AAA BBB CCC`" is a town, so it could be "`AAA BBB CCC`", "`AAA BBB`", "`AAA-BBB-CCC`", "`AAA`", "`L'AAA`", "`D'AAA BBB`", "`D'AAA..`". Well, the end of the line just after the number is the town name.

So a big file containings lines like:

```
06260 Puget Théniers
06620 Bar sur Loup (Le)
06640 SAINT JEANNET
06640 Saint Jeannet
06660 AURON
06660 SAINT ETIENNE DE TINEE
06660 Saint Etienne de Tinée
06670 Levens
06710 Touët sur Var
06750 ANDON
06750 Thorenc
```

Would end up in something like

```
SOUNDEX("Puget Théniers") AND CP="06260"
SOUNDEX("Bar sur Loup (Le)") AND CP="06620"
SOUNDEX("SAINT JEANNET") AND CP="06640"
SOUNDEX("Saint Jeannet") AND CP="06640"
SOUNDEX("AURON") AND CP="06660"
SOUNDEX("SAINT ETIENNE DE TINEE") AND CP="06660"
SOUNDEX("Saint Etienne de Tinée") AND CP="06660"
SOUNDEX("Levens") AND CP="06670"
SOUNDEX("Touët sur Var") AND CP="06710"
SOUNDEX("ANDON") AND CP="06750"
SOUNDEX("Thorenc") AND CP="06750"
```

What is the best/cleanest way to start with?

I know that I could do this in bash shellusing regular expressions, but I've already done a big parser in python that output lines like this. So I'd like to finish all of this in Python, and that's why I'm looking for a clean code & some explanation, because I may have a lot of "filters" like this to do in the future.

[update] `13480` is something that should always be numbers, and if it's not, should raise an exception.

Comment: Use SQL parameters as supported by your SQL connection library instead. Do *not* try and insert values into SQL queries like this with string formatting.

Comment: And this is not a real question; what have you tried and what problems did you run into? I'd expect a user with 4k rep to know by now we can help you with practical issues, not with give-me-the-codez questions.

Comment: Starting with regular expression will allow to make the solution be adapted to a variety of inputs more easily.

Comment: Agreed @Martijn. Please update your question with something that exhibits a bit of effort on your side in the form of an attempt.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you readcarefully the code, there's nowhere an "**`INSERT`**" in database.

Comment: @OlivierPons: Not *YET*. I can insert one. Just because you do a select here doesn't mean that you cannot inject anything!

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't express myself properly. It's about regular expression, and about being sure the `13480` in my sample is always numbers.

Comment: Are you *matching* the `SELECT` or are you *generating* that text? You never need regular expressions to generate text.

Comment: @Pieters Don't you think that using ``re.sub()`` is generation of text ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm planning to do a select on my `safe` virtual machine for each record, and if a record gives a result, then I'm going to generate (in another batch) the good "insert" queries. The code I'm planning to do is to be thrown away: it's made for just **one** use. But, like learning bash shell, I'd like to know some of the basis of regular expressions and how to use them properly, with real world example (= my example)

Comment: @OlivierPons: Why not *expand* your question to include more detail then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters because if the question is too *specific* (and it's already quite specific from my p.o.v.) it may be closed. But now, the question I'm asking seems to be not specific enough and 2 votes "down", and 3 asked for close. I don't get that: you have to ask a question that is not *too much* specific and *enough* specific... I feel like talking to my wife: it feels like two deaf people trying to speak & hear each other. **`{>_<}`**

Comment: @OlivierPons: Your question is *not clear at all*. I cannot figure out what you are trying to do. There is the impression you are trying to generate text, but I am not certain. It is not clear what you want to do with your input; perhaps you thought you could use regular expression matching to extract certain types of data from it, but I am not certain. There is only one input example, one output example, and nothing telling me how you expect the one to lead to the other. As a result we are all *guessing* what you want.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am trying to kindof "filter" a text. I could have done it in bash shell, in Delphi, maybe in C or anything, but I've already done a parser in Python (because it needed much more than simple `awk` or `grep` filtering), so I'd like to finish this in python, and add a "filter" to have all in one "python script". And like I said, I'll just use it once, but I'll keep it ready for another use, or as a good example for later use, because I will learn how to use properly python, and "python regexp string manipulation". This is this knowledge I'm asking for and to share with everyone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've updated my question, I hope it'll be clearer.

Comment: @OlivierPons: Yes, the difference is *huge*; it is now much clearer as to what you wanted to do.

Comment: @Olivier Pons I wish you to write me in my email: eyguem@gmail.com. Take care of the G, not Q in the address. I have an answer for your question but I am obliged to write in english to a French like I am, someone edited an answer that I had posted, in which edit he changed the meaning of my answer, everybody seems wanting to prove you that you musn't use regexes, they don't understand your question (which I have understood 2 hours ago), and now that I want to post, the question is closed. It does a lot of difficulties and I have no time to waste here, struggling against oppositions.

Comment: Yes I'll write to your email, even though I found the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (more complicated):

```
import re
str = "13480 D'AAA-BBB CCC..."
result = re.search("([\d]+)\s([\w\s\x27\x2E\x2C\x2D]+)",str)

print(result.group(1)) # will print "13480"
print(result.group(2)) # will print "D'AAA-BBB CCC..."
```

A super simple solution:

```
str = "13480 D'AAA-BBB CCC..."
result = str.split(' ',1)

print(result[0]) # will print "13480"
print(result[1]) # will print "D'AAA-BBB CCC..."
```

Now you have to use results from group(1) and group(2) or result[0] and result[1] to create SQL query. But I advise you to use parameterized query, instead of simple string operations (to avoid SQL injection).

Comment: +1 for sql-injection warning

Comment: It can't be SQL injection as it's already sanitized with `htmlentities()`. Thank you for the warning

Comment: I've just updated my question: it is possible with your solution that "AAA BBB CCC" can contain any character (like in my updated question)?

Comment: Thank you very much! I've copied-paste your code, tried with `"4410 Arzacq Arraziguet"` and it didn't work.

Comment: Strange... works for me. What error do you get?

Comment: The second simple solution without regex will work for all you examples

Comment: Your #1 solution was good, the problem was my copy paste which copied strange char instead of a space, even though it was looking like a space. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

```
'SELECT XX FROM YY WHERE SOUNDEX("{1} {2} {3}")=FIELD1 AND CP="{0}"'\
    .format(*'13480 AAA BBB CCC'.split())
```

This one-liner will do, you can also use some [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

But it is definitely **not** what you want to use. As *Martijn* commented, you *should not* build your SQL expressions manually. Use a wrapper around your SQL base - [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) or the universal [**sqlalchemy**](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) (you will end up with the latter eventually)

With `sqlalchemy` you would end up with something like that:

```
input_id, input_fields = input_line.split(maxsplit=1)
selection = (session.query(YY_Table)
                    .filter(YY_Table.field1=input_fields)
                    .filter(YY_Table.cp=input_id))
```

(All this under condition that you do a proper script. If you write a single throw-away code that massages your database, then feel free to use `split`, RegEx or even VIM scripting)

Comment: Hello. I deleted my answer because someone translated from french to english (not a real problem) but changing the content of what I said. However, there was a comment from you I didn't understand: _""device discovered"_ . What does it mean please ?

Comment: It was just a Mac-user joke, no offense :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)

Comment: OK, thank you. I didn't feel offensed. I am not anglophone and sometimes I wonder about phrases I don't understand. - I will delete these comments after a certain time.

Comment: Sorry I didn't express myself properly "AAA BBB CCC" is a town, so it could be "AAA BBB CCC", "AAA BBB", "AAA-BBB-CCC", "AAA" and so on. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Replace yourdbms with the library of your choice
# Be sure to use the library's tokens (%s, ?, etc.)

import yourdbms

sql = """
    SELECT XX FROM YY 
    WHERE SOUNDEX(%s)=FIELD1 AND
          CP=%s
    """
conx = yourdbms.connect(your_db_info)
cursor = conx.cursor()
with open('path/to/yourfile', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Get the params without regex
        pos = line.find(' ')
        params = line[pos+1:], int(line[:pos])
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
        do_something_with(cursor)
cursor.close()
conx.close()
```

Comment: I'm sorry I may not express myself properly, the question is about python and regexp, nothing to do with SQL. I'll update my question to be clearer. Sorry again.

Comment: You don't really need regular expressions to solve your problem.  You are introducing unnecessary overhead and exposing yourself to SQL injection.  Based on your updated question, this can be solved fairly easily.  I'll update my answer.  If you are just using a contrived example, I'd pick a less "sensitive" topic :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split these lines on the first space:

```
for line in inputfile:
    code, town = line.strip().split(None, 1)
```

Now you can further process this information. If you want to use this to query a database, I would *not* generate the SQL query text. Instead use SQL parameters:

```
cursor.select('SELECT XX FROM YY WHERE SOUNDEX(?)=FIELD1 AND CP=?', (town, code))
```

This has several advantages:

1. You don't have to worry about how to properly escape the parameters. This is important when preventing SQL injection attacks, but also when dealing with arbitrary data from a file where input data could potentially contain SQL-specific special characters.
2. The database is given the opportunity to prepare the statement, creating a query plan that can be reused for future queries. If you are doing a lot of such queries, that makes a huge difference.